# SVNKit : list of updated / added files in a working copy after update operation

Tags: java, amazon-s3, svnkit

I am trying to upload a bunch of property files placed in a directory to S3.

I have shared some details in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214798/s3-static-resource-update-on-regular-basis-using-java-or-shell-script.

As a solution, I am trying to do following:

1. Commit property files to SVN reposity from anywhere.
2. Checkout the property files to a Working copy on a local machine(LM).
3. Use SVNKit to write an update task.
4. Use S3 API to Upload only updated /added files in Working copy.

I have done Update and Upload to S3. But I am facing difficuly in getting list of added / updated files. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

You may set an `ISVNEventHandler` for the `SvnUpdate` and collect events on touched files in `#handleEvent`. However, this is not really a robust solution, IMO.

Instead:

- make sure that you are on a clean revision before the update (alternatively use `SvnStatusSummary` to determine the minimum local revision present),
- remember this revision number,
- perform the `SvnUpdate`,
- check the log between the old and new revision, and finally
- determine all touched files (there may be duplicates of course when changing a file a couple of times or redundant files when changing a file forth and back).

Comment: I took your suggestion of using ISVNEventHandler. Somehow, event.getPath method is not working for me. COLLECTING REVISIONS:  I am not using InfoHandler. I am going through the directory recusively, taking revisions of all files and putting them in a map. Then I am applying Update on Wroking copy. Then I am again collecting revisions and putting them in a diffrerent map. Comparing these two maps can give me updated files as well as new files.

Comment: The approach seems fine. I'm using SVNKit 1.7.x. There is just an `SVNEvent#getFile()`, but no `SVNEvent#getPath()`. For older versions, I'm quite sure there is a `SVNEvent#getFile()` which should work well, too.